# Generate Complex Object from LINQ to XML in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have an XML File that I am processing using LINQ.  I want to basically serialize the XML data into custom objects but don't know how.

Simplified XML

```
<Data>
   <Group id="1">
      <Child id="1"/>
      <Child id="2"/>
      <Child id="3"/>
   </Group>
   <Group id="2">
      <Child id="1"/>
      <Child id="2"/>
      <Child id="3"/>
   </Group>
</Data>
```

I have a class called Group with a property called Children that is a list of (Child).

I can do the following in linq to generate the Enurable( of Group):

```
 dim g = From item In _
 XElement.Load("XMLFile.xml", LoadOptions.None)...<Group> _
 Select New nABLE4ConfigInfo.Group(item.@id)
```

How can I finish the above LINQ query to populate the Children property of the Group object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as nested select statements and the right constructor on the class.

```
 Dim g = From item In _
      XElement.Load("XMLFile.xml", LoadOptions.None)...<Group> _
             Select New Group(id:=item.@id, _
                   Children:=(From c In item...<Child>  Select c.@id).ToList)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this class, paired with `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`, will do the trick:

```
<Serializable> _
Public Class Data

   <Serializable> _
   Public Class Group

       <Serializable> _
       Public Class Child
           <XmlAttribute> _
           Public id As Integer
       End Class


       <XmlArray> _
       Public Child() As Child

       <XmlAttribute> _
       Public id As Integer

   End Class

  <XmlArray> _
  Public Group() As Group
End Class
```

The class may need some work yet: getting the arrays right can be tricky.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer.  The XML I presented is greatly simplified.  I use XML serialization throughout this application but can not for this.

Comment: Well this isn't the only way: there are at least 1/2 dozen different ways to handle xml in .Net.  You're using an XDocument and I showed you serialization, but there's also XmlDocument or DataSet.ReadXml(), to name a couple.  You could read by hand, if you have to.

Comment: I understand.  Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I already have a method that handles this using the XML DOM and works just fine.  I just wanted a solution using LINQ since it's much cleaner.